# list ToDictionary with a new generated key using Linq

Tags: linq, dictionary

I have a list of objects that I want to turn into a dictionary with a new index key. Here is a simple example:

Original:
"alpha"
"beta"
"charlie"

I want:
1, "alpha"
2, "beta"
3, "charlie"

I can solve it this way:

```
void Main()
{
    var slist = new List<string>();
    slist.Add("alpha");
    slist.Add("beta");
    slist.Add("charlie");

    int i=0;
    var v = slist.ToDictionary (s => i++ );

    slist.Dump();
    v.Dump();
}
```

Is it any shorter/smarter way to solve this? For example avoid int i = 0 in the line before the query?

Comment: You don't need to increment anything at all, if your objects are going to be numbered sequentially (1, 2, 3....), why don't you just keep it as a list? The indexer on the list will serve as your key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overload of `Select` to get the index.

```
var v = slist.Select((s,i) => new {s, i})
             .ToDictionary(x => x.i + 1,  x => x.s);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var v = slist.ToDictionary(s => slist.IndexOf(s) + 1);
```